# Colortext program doesn't color properly

Tags: c, colors, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, argv

I'm trying to make a simple "color text" program in C that uses windows.h to change the terminal color (command-line program) and compiling using tcc. However, instead of working like it should, it picks a random color depending on the text given (Even control characters!), instead of actually just normally passing the number. How would i fix that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc >= 3) {
        printf("Too many arguments specified.");
        return 1;
    }
    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("No arguments specified. Please specify one.");
        return 1;
    }
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), *argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

So, if i for example type 0 (which should bring me to all black text), i instead get this:

[image: not expected, should just make it black]

EDIT: Looks like changing `*argv[1]` to `strlen(argv[1]);` worked. However, now it depends on the length of the input specified, rather than the number given. It atleast sets the background and foreground correctly (a length of 0 gives an error, a length of 1 changes it to 1, a length of whatever sets it to whatever, etc.), and using a "anti strlen" (takes a number, and makes a string with the number many letters, and returns it) doesn't work.

EDIT: Using atoi(); fixed my problem:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), atoi(argv[1]));
    return 0;
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *are* getting the color you specified.

Here is why: ".. instead of actually just normally passing the number ..." but `argv[1]` does *not* "pass a number"! Program arguments are *always* passed as strings.

[`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047(v=vs.85).aspx) sets the console character color to the value provided. The [character attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_character_attributes) are defined by bits, but that MSDN page only lists their symbolic names. Looking in `wincon.h` shows their actual assignments:

```
#define FOREGROUND_BLUE 1
#define FOREGROUND_GREEN    2
#define FOREGROUND_RED  4
#define FOREGROUND_INTENSITY    8
#define BACKGROUND_BLUE 16
#define BACKGROUND_GREEN    32
#define BACKGROUND_RED  64
#define BACKGROUND_INTENSITY    128
```

What value *do* you sent, then? The first character of the string `"0"` – that is, a decimal code of `48`, or in hex `0x30`. This – look at the defines – comes down to `BACKGROUND_BLUE + BACKGROUND_GREEN` = cyan.

The funny thing is, since you want black-on-black, there is no obvious way to enter a *binary* `0` as a command argument. I suggest you enter the required color code in decimal or hex notation, rather than as a "raw" value, and use `strtol` or a similar function to convert it to a binary value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows you could use `conio.h` and use it this way:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   textcolor(RED);
   cprintf("some stuff");

   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Just pay attention, `conio.h`is a non-standart library which is not present on Unix.

Comment: conio.h doesn't work on tcc for Windows (doesn't know what RED is, or BLINK, or even textcolor...)

Comment: If it doesn't work, you could give a try with `curses.h`, which is another library which can bring a solution to your problem.